# Error after save form [Symfony3]

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

**MyEntityType:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $em = $this->em;
        $em = $options['entity_manager'];
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('photo', FileType::class)
            ->add('kitchen', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'DeliveryAdminBundle:Kitchen',
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (\Delivery\AdminBundle\Repository\KitchenRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('k')
                        ->orderBy('k.title', 'ASC');

                },
                'data' => ['16'=>'Японская'],        
            ))
            ->add('specialization', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'DeliveryAdminBundle:Specialization',
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (\Delivery\AdminBundle\Repository\SpecializationRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('k')
                        ->orderBy('k.title', 'ASC');

                },
            ))
            ->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'DeliveryAdminBundle:EntityType',
                'multiple' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (\Delivery\AdminBundle\Repository\EntityTypeRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('k')
                        ->orderBy('k.title', 'ASC');

                },
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Отправить'));
    }
```

**Controller Action:**

```
    public function newAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('DeliveryAdminBundle:MyEntity');

        $entity = new MyEntity();
        $form = $this->createForm(MyEntityType::class, $entity, [
            'entity_manager' => $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request); // ERROR !!!

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $repo->update($entity, $request->request->get('id'));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('show_myentity');
        }

        return $this->render( 'DeliveryAdminBundle:Entity:new.html.twig', 
                array('form'=>$form->createView()) );
    }
```

The project is published https://github.com/zchipirov/delivery

Set up communication between the tables Kitchen->MyEntity (OneToMany) and Specialization->MyEntity (OneToMany). The table "MyEntityKitchen" and "MyEntitySpecialization" union MyEntity, Kitchen and Specialization

After save I have error:

```
Expected argument of type "Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization", "Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\Kitchen" given
```

**Stack:**

```
if (null === $response) {
$msg .=' Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?';
}
throw new \LogicException($msg);
}
}
return $this->filterResponse($response, $request, $type);




at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), 1)
in var\cache\dev\classes.php at line 4855  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), 1, true)
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php at line 168  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in web\app_dev.php at line 28  +
```

Comment: Could you please paste stack trace?

Comment: >Could you please paste stack trace?
Okey

Comment: Below is my answer that should fix you error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have in `MyEntity` class:

```
/**
 * Add kitchen
 *
 * @param \Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $kitchen
 *
 * @return MyEntity
 */
public function addKitchen(\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $kitchen)
{
    $this->kitchen[] = $kitchen;
    return $this;
}
```

and in form you have:

```
->add('kitchen', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'DeliveryAdminBundle:Kitchen',
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder' => function (\Delivery\AdminBundle\Repository\KitchenRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('k')
            ->orderBy('k.title', 'ASC');
        },
    'data' => ['16'=>'Японская'],        
))
```

and when submitting form entity of class `\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\Kitchen` is passed to `MyEntity->addKitchen`. That's ok but for some reason you have there type: `\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization` and that's why `PHP` is throwing `Exception`.

Change [this line](https://github.com/zchipirov/delivery/blob/master/src/Delivery/AdminBundle/Entity/MyEntity.php#L792) to:

```
public function addKitchen(\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\Kitchen $kitchen)
```

and [this line](https://github.com/zchipirov/delivery/blob/master/src/Delivery/AdminBundle/Entity/MyEntity.php#L804) to:

```
public function removeKitchen(\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\Kitchen $kitchen)
```

Comment: Thanks! After save I get error: `code`Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntity#$kitchen", got "Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\Kitchen" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I added code:

```
/**
     * Add kitchen
     *
     * @param \Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $kitchen
     *
     * @return MyEntity
     */
    public function addKitchen(\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $kitchen, \Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $specialization)
    {
        $this->kitchen[] = $kitchen;
        $this->specialization[] = $specialization;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove kitchen
     *
     * @param \Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $kitchen
     */
    public function removeKitchen(\Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $kitchen, \Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntitySpecialization $specialization)
    {
        $this->kitchen->removeElement($kitchen);
        $this->specialization->removeElement($specialization);
    }
```

Thanks, it's works!

How I can save data from Form into multiple tables (from MyEntityType to MyEntity, MyEntityKitchen and MyEntitySpecialization)?
**After save I get error:**

```
Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\MyEntity#$kitchen", got "Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\Kitchen" instead.
```

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?